# Telegram bot won't send message to group

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

have a problem with telegram bot. Bot is in 5 groups. Sending works fine to 4 groups. Bot can't send any message to 1 group and don't understand why.

Any help / idea please?
Bot is in all groups of course.

```
$apiToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$data = [
'chat_id' => '-11223344556677889900',
'text' => "TEST"
];
$response = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot$apiToken/sendMessage?" . http_build_query($data) );
```

Comment: Are you sure that `chat_id` exist?
I prefer using `error_log` and check what is the error

Comment: yes of course. how can I enable error_log please?

Comment: Use `error_log` and you'll find the logging in logs file, If you don't know use `sendMessage` to yourself to get what is the error

Comment: Are those groups different in any way?  Do they contain some special names, or anything else? Can you post to those groups with the bot account manually somehow? Or with some other account? Did you try creating some other 5 groups, did it work in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://core.telegram.org/bots) does not mention but i have been using 1 bot to send messages to 10 groups. it works normally.
There is no limit to the number of groups the bot can send messages . lease double check the group id.

Comment: rechecked group it 3x, still same error :/ any way to see logs why it bot can't send message?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems, solve it:

1. test send http-request direct from browser:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<tocken>/sendMessage?text=%27test%27&chat_id=@channel_name
```

2. prepare args and request 'manually':

```
function build_args($arr){
   $str = '';
   foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
      $str .= "$key=$val&";
   }
   return rtrim($str,'&');
}

$data = array('chat_id' => $channel, 'text' => $msg, 'parse_mode'=>'Markdown');
$easy_query = build_args($data);
        $req = $url_bot."/sendMessage?".$easy_query;
return json_decode( file_get_contents($req), true);
```

3. Anywhere if you will have a working step 1 then try to create same request in php